# PHP 5.6 upgrade, xDebug extension version mismatch

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug, git-bash

I have recently updated my PHP from 5.5 to 5.6 . I have installed xDebug compatible version to go with my PHP 5.6 from xdebug.org. This seems to work.

Problem that I'm having is that when I run php -v on my win machine (git bash) I get the xDebug version mismatch and the following message.

> Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220121212.
>   The Zend Engine API version 220131226 which is installed, is newer.
>   Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of
>   Xdebug.
>   PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 12:21:49)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

One of the posts that I was able to find seemed to fix this issue but on MAC OS.
[link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517776/php-5-6-upgrade-compiled-old-extensions/41769499#41769499)

Can someone please help, advise what should I do.

Comment: This has helped me solved this issue... https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize